# I deleted disk partitions - installing Ubuntu 11.04 to WIN7 build - I need windows back but how?

Tags: windows-7, data-recovery, partitioning

> Steps to **disaster**
>
> 1. Installed Ubuntu 11.04
> 2. Partitioned drive upon install and gave Ubuntu entire disk.
>
> Several months later I need WIN7 as dual boot
>
> **What happens at present**
>
> Booting into WIN7 via F9 option at boot .. takes me to Ubuntu. It
>   describes 'preparing to boot from Windows' but screen goes purple and
>   it comes up with Ubuntu instead.
>
> Booting normally : machine either makes a horrible beeping
>   (continious) and blank screen or boots in Ubuntu or a mix of beeping
>   initially then fires up Ubuntu. (to be honest best to F9 to get into
>   Ubuntu .. seems the cleaner option)
>
> **Using a script I have obtained the following disk information:**

**Grub2 (v1.99)** is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 1 of the same hard drive for core.img. 
core.img is at this location and looks for (,msdos1)/boot/grub on this drive.

**Windows** is installed in the MBR of **/dev/sdb.sda1:**

(*obviously no partition exists on the drive - that's my understanding and my knowledge of unix/linux/ubuntu is limited*)

nb.there is a ref to sda1 at the bottom of this script for grub (grub2 is installed) which is `sda1/boot/grub/grub.cfg`:

```
File system: ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info:  
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 11.04
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab /boot/grub/core.img

sda2: 

File system:       Extended Partition
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info:  

sda5: 

File system:       swap
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info:  

sdb1: 

File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  Windows XP: FAT32
    Boot sector info:   No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /bootmgr /boot/bcd



Drive: sda 

Disk /dev/sda: 160.0 GB, 160041885696 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 19457 cylinders, total 312581808 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sda1    *          2,048   310,503,423   310,501,376  83 Linux
/dev/sda2         310,505,470   312,580,095     2,074,626   5 Extended
/dev/sda5         310,505,472   312,580,095     2,074,624  82 Linux swap / Solaris


Drive: sdb 

Disk /dev/sdb: 8004 MB, 8004304896 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 973 cylinders, total 15633408 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sdb1    *             63    15,633,407    15,633,345   c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

`blkid` output:

```
Device           UUID                                   TYPE       LABEL

/dev/sda1        94108733-fa78-47f3-b04d-31fb682e442e   ext4       
/dev/sda5        4c57bb9e-d799-4c06-a5ad-c1ddbcbb46d3   swap       
/dev/sdb1        6B1C-F558                              vfat
```

Mount points:

```
Device           Mount_Point              Type       Options

/dev/sda1        /                        ext4       (rw,errors=remount-ro,commit=0)
/dev/sdb1        /media/6B1C-F558         vfat       (rw,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks,uid=1000,gid=1000,shortname=mixed,dmask=0077,utf8=1,showexec,flush)
```

**sda1/boot/grub/grub.cfg:**

> So how do I retrieve either (in order of preference)
>
> 1. Dual boot with Windows 7
> 2. Win7 complete reinstall.

**N.B I have no data that requires saving and I have the Windows device drives and a Ubuntu 11.10 install package**

> Hurdles to overcome:
>
> 1. It's Acer One laptop with **no DVD/CD drive**
> 2. Installing WIN7 from a Flash Drive bombs out as it cannot recognise any system devices as the drivers are not installed/accessible.
>
> My gut feeling is that I a) need to install Ubuntu fresh and
>   repartition the drive but I am unsure how much damage it will do .. or
>   b) partition the drive from within Ubuntu and stick windows files on
>   there and reallocate the pointer .. but not sure how to make it
>   visible on boot as C:\ ??

Answer (score 1):

If I'm discerning what you're saying correctly and you installed Ubuntu on the drive in which Windows 7 used to be installed, then you can't bring it back (if you still have it on one of your partitions, then [this utility](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) can help you repair your boot).

I'm not sure why you have trouble with installing Windows from a flash drive. Are you suggesting that it would work from a CD? In any case, if you can't install Windows that way, you can't install it at all. I believe at one point during the installation Windows gives you the option of loading additional drivers. If you have a driver disk for your laptop, perhaps you can try copying it on a flash drive and have the installer load the drivers.